# how to dispatch a specific method with csrf_exempt in django class based view

Tags: python, django, view, csrf

I am trying to set `csrf_exempt` on class-based view in Django I've tried this one:

Now, my class is look like this:

```
class UserView(View):

   # Check csrf here  
   def get(self, request, pk):
      #code here

   # I want to exempt csrf checking only on this method 
   def post(self, request):
       #code here
```

Meanwhile, if I use `@method_decorator(csrf_exempt, name='dispatch')` it will be applied to every method in the class. What's the best approach to exempt only for a specific method in a class-based view in Django?

Comment: CSRF only makes sense in the context of POST anyway. It's not enforced on GET.

Comment: @DanielRoseman crsf also apply to PUT, DELETE, etc

Comment: @HenryM i just want to apply `csrf_exempt` to specific method. for instance only to `put` or only to `post`

Answer (score 2):

You can't dacorate only the `post()`/`put()` because `as_view` function in [base.py](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/base.py/#L49) doesn't carry `__dict__` methods from other methods than `dispatch()`. [Source](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/15794).
You can only decorate a class or override the `dispatch()` method as [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-the-class) says.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this -

```py
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator

class UserView(View):

   # Check csrf here  
   def get(self, request, pk):
      #code here

   # exempt csrf will affect only this method 
   @method_decorator(csrf_exempt)
   def post(self, request):
       #code here
```

You can also write it this way -

```py
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator


@method_decorator(csrf_exempt, name='post')
class UserView(View):

   # Check csrf here  
   def get(self, request, pk):
      #code here

   # exempt csrf will affect only post method
   def post(self, request):
       #code here
```

Read the [documentation here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-the-class).